# Issue with Infite Loop

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a problem. This code is not giving the results it should. It should out number to large to the console and for some reason it is ignoring the if the statement when doing this. Also, in this program `InputNum` should remain of the long data type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/*
Function Name: CalculateBinary
CalculateBinary takes a number from the main function and finds its binary form.
*/

void CalculateBinary(long InputNum)
{   
    //Takes InputNum and divides it down to "1" or "0" so that it can be put in binary form.
    if ( InputNum != 1 && InputNum != 0)
        CalculateBinary(InputNum/2);

    // If the number has no remainder it outputs a "0". Otherwise it outputs a "1". 
    if (InputNum % 2 == 0)
        cout << "0";
    else
        cout << "1";
}


void main()
{
    // Where the current number will be stored
    long InputNum = 3000000000;

    //Opens the text file and inputs first number into InputNum. 
//  ifstream fin("binin.txt");
//  fin >> InputNum;

    // While Input number is not 0 the loop will continue to evaluate, getting a new number each time.
    while (InputNum >= 0)
    {
        if(InputNum > 1000000000)
            cout << "Number too large for this program ....";
        else
            CalculateBinary(InputNum);

        cout << endl;
        //fin >> InputNum;      
    }
}
```

Comment: the logic in function if `CalculateBinary()` is not very clear. The condition `if ( InputNum != 1 && InputNum != 0)CalculateBinary(InputNum/2);` will make sure you go past this condition only when `InputNum = 1 or 0` then what is the use of `if (InputNum % 2 == 0)` is not very clear

Comment: Just a hint, what do you get if you use an unsigned long instead of a long....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CalculateBinary(InputNum)` does NOT modify the value of `InputNum`, so its value would be always the same (300000000) and the while loop never end.

Comment: I'm not sure OP was expecting it to change - that looks like code left in to handle reading numbers from a file as per the commented out code (eg, 10, 7, 4, -1). That doesn't make your answer less valid of course since it _will_ always be 30...something.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is not being ignored; you just aren't modifying `InputNum`.  Its always going to keep its initial value.   You are passing `InputNum` by value, not by reference.  Therefore, `CalculateBinary()` is using a copy of `InputNum`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be infinite. That's because you have a:

```
while (InputNum >= 0)
```

line in `main` but you *never change the value of InputNum!*

Remove the `while` loop altogether. It looks like you may need it when you start reading your numbers in from `binin.txt` but certainly not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are expecting the last number in the file to be less than 0 to terminate your program.  Instead it's better to detect the end of the file.  Try uncommenting your file code and using the while condition instead:

```
while (fin.good())
```